# Subconsulta devuelve más de una fila

Tags: sql

Tengo un pequeño problema con una sentencia SQL. A la hora de lanzar la sentencia, funciona, pero en los campos donde hago subconsultas me sale el mismo dato ya que no hago un **group by**. Pero claro, al poner un group by en las subconsultas, me sale que devuelve más de una fila.

```
SELECT idload,
count(*) as "Llamadas totales",

(select COUNT(idload) from ocm_log_calls 
where idcampaign=4 and fecha>='2020-08-20' 
and Fecha<='2020-08-24 23:59:59' 
and timecall!=0 GROUP BY idload) 
as Llamadas_contestadas,

(select count(*) from ocm_log_calls 
where idcampaign=4 and fecha>='2020-08-20' 
and Fecha<='2020-08-24 23:59:59' ) 
as Llamadas_NO_contestadas,

(select round((select Llamadas_contestadas/(select count(*)from ocm_log_calls
where idcampaign=4 and fecha>='2020-08-20' 
and Fecha<='2020-08-24 23:59:59')*100), 2)) 
as Porcentaje

from ocm_log_calls 
where idcampaign=4 
group by idload;
```

[image: Información de la sentencia]

La cuestión es que, cada select count(*) tiene que devolver diferentes resultados cuando pones un **group by**.

[image: Primera sentencia]

Cuando pongo un group by en los select que devuelven la información de la segunda captura, me sale que el select devuelve varias filas.
[image: Multiple rows]

Se que es tema del group by y que a lo mejor tengo que ponerlo de otro manera para que me muestre esta información.

Comment: Hola pues si te va a salir el mismo dato porque los where siempre son los mismos para todas las filas

Comment: En preguntas de este tipo es buena idea incluir: La explicación más clara que te sea posible de lo que quieres lograr, algunos datos de ejemplo de la tabla origen y el resultado esperado con esos datos de ejemplo. En su estado actual, a pesar de haber leído la pregunta 2 veces, no queda para nada claro ni lo que quieres conseguir, ni el problema que estás teniendo con la consulta que ya escribiste.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que requieres es realizar subconsultas como esa, es mejor que las realices en un join, por que en rendimiento sera mejor para tu consulta al realizar una vez el agrupado y posterior el join,
Cuando la realizas en el select ejecuta cada subconsulta por cada registro.

```
SELECT idload,
    count(*) as [Llamadas totales],
    contestadas.Cantidad as [Llamadas_contestadas],
    NOcontestadas.Cantidad as [Llamadas_NO_contestadas],
    CASE WHEN NOcontestadas.Cantidad = 0 OR NOcontestadas.Cantidad IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE contestadas.Cantidad / NOcontestadas.Cantidad END as [Porcentaje]
from ocm_log_calls olc
    left join (
        select idload, COUNT(*) as [Cantidad]
        from ocm_log_calls
        where idcampaign=4
            and fecha>='2020-08-20' 
            and Fecha<='2020-08-24 23:59:59' 
            and timecall!=0
        GROUP BY idload
    ) contestadas ON olc.idload=contestadas.idload
    left join (
        select idload, count(*) as [Cantidad]
        from ocm_log_calls 
        where idcampaign=4
            and fecha>='2020-08-20' 
            and Fecha<='2020-08-24 23:59:59'
            and timecall=0
        GROUP BY idload
    ) NOcontestadas ON olc.idload=NOcontestadas.idload
where idcampaign=4 
    and fecha>='2020-08-20' 
    and Fecha<='2020-08-24 23:59:59' 
group by idload, contestadas.Cantidad, NOcontestadas.Cantidad;
```

Y una forma mas rapido de realizarla es hacer la suma en la consulta, aplicando los criterios de timecall para sumar o no.

```
SELECT idload,
    count(*) as [Llamadas totales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN timecall!=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Llamadas_contestadas],
    SUM(CASE WHEN timecall=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Llamadas_NO_contestadas],
    CASE WHEN SUM( CASE WHEN timecall=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN  timecall!=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN  timecall=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END [Porcentaje]
from ocm_log_calls
where idcampaign=4 
    and fecha>='2020-08-20' 
    and Fecha<='2020-08-24 23:59:59' 
group by idload;
```

En el porcentaje hago una validación para que no marque error de división entre 0.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema ya que las subconsultas deben de estar relacionadas para que puedan regresar solo los valores correspondientes a una fila en particular. Eso se hace agregando al `where` una referencia comparación de la columna idload entre la tabla de la consulta general y la tabla de la subconsulta.

Sin embargo, eso es una solución ineficiente tanto en código como en rendimiento. Lo mejor sería hacer conteos (o cualquier agregado) condicionales. De esa forma, el código queda mucho más sencillo.

```
SELECT idload,
    COUNT(*) as "Llamadas totales",
    COUNT( CASE WHEN timecall != 0 THEN idload END) AS Llamadas_contestadas,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN timecall = 0 --¿Falta esto?
                    THEN idload END) AS Llamadas_NO_contestadas,
    ROUND(COUNT( CASE WHEN timecall != 0 THEN idload END) * 100. / count(*), 2) AS Porcentaje
FROM  ocm_log_calls 
WHERE idcampaign =  4
AND   fecha      >= '2020-08-20' 
AND   fecha      <= '2020-08-24 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY idload;
```